# Saving images from the web-camera

Tags: java, image, webcam, jmf

Language: Java
It is used in addition: JMF

Below is the code (without the Swing-forms), which allows to capture the image with WEB-cameras:

```
MediaLocator getWebCam = new MediaLocator("vfw://0");
    private Player player;
    Timer timer = new Timer(40, this);

    public BufferedImage grabFrameImage() {

        Image image = null;
        FrameGrabbingControl frameGrabbingControl = null;

        if (player != null)
            frameGrabbingControl = (FrameGrabbingControl) player.getControl("javax.media.control.FrameGrabbingControl");
        Buffer buffer = frameGrabbingControl.grabFrame();
        if (buffer != null)
            image = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buffer.getFormat()).createImage(buffer);
        if (image != null)
            return (BufferedImage) image;

        return null;
    }

    public WorkWithWebCam() throws NoDataSourceException, IOException, NoPlayerException {

            initComponents();
            player = Manager.createPlayer(Manager.createDataSource(getWebCam));
            player.start();

    }
private void jButton1ActionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        timer.start();
    }

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        EventQueue.invokeLater(new Runnable() {
            public void run() {
                try{
                    new WorkWithWebCam().setVisible(true);
                }catch(Exception ex){}
            }
        });
    }

    public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panelMain.getGraphics().drawImage(this.grabFrameImage(), 0, 0, 400, 300, null);
    }
```

Can you please tell how to save an image with a web-camera?

Looking ahead, we extended the method actionPerformed:

```
public void actionPerformed(ActionEvent e) {
        panelMain.getGraphics().drawImage(this.grabFrameImage(), 0, 0, 400, 300, null);
        BufferedImage image = new BufferedImage(400, 300, BufferedImage.TYPE_INT_RGB);
        String fileOut = "temp.jpg";
        Graphics g = image.getGraphics();
        panelMain.paint(g);
        try {
            ImageIO.write(image, "jpg", new FileOutputStream(fileOut));
        } catch (IOException e1) {
            e1.printStackTrace();  //To change body of catch statement use File | Settings | File Templates.
        }

    }
```

The only thing, no picture is saved with a web-camera, and the white background with a vertical stripe on the right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
image = new BufferToImage((VideoFormat) buffer.getFormat()).createImage(buffer);
ImageIO.write(image, "png", new File("screengrab.png"));
```

See [`ImageIO.write(RenderedImage,String,File)`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/imageio/ImageIO.html#write%28java.awt.image.RenderedImage,%20java.lang.String,%20java.io.File%29) for details.